# PHP conditional if is_page array

Tags: php, wordpress

Can this be written in a way to use less php code?

```
<?php if (! is_page( array( 'about-us', 'privacy-policy'  ) ) ) : echo'
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get A Quote:</h2>
                <div id="city-page-form" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div>'; endif; ?><?php if (! is_page( array( 'about-us', 'privacy-policy'  ) ) ) : echo do_shortcode( '[wpforms id="10" title="false" description="false"]' ); endif; ?><?php if (! is_page( array( 'about-us', 'privacy-policy'  ) ) ) : echo'</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
'; endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think your question fits better in https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you post on CR please read the help center pages like [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), lest it be closed as off-topic